# Delete all data from Mongo database

Tags: mongodb

How do I drop **all** collections from a Mongo database? I know about `db.dropDatabase()`, but it also removes users. I want to retain database users, just purge all the data.

Comment: if you don't want to drop the database, then you have to drop all collections separately (except users). Use ```db.collection_name_here.drop()```

Comment: Just to clarify: I mean system users, not `users` collection. When removing everything manually like you've suggested I got an error on `system.indexes`, but I can live with that if there's no better solution.

Comment: oh, that was a misunderstanding then. However, I don't think there is another way, by maybe someone else can help